# Redirecting a web folder directory to another htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry this has no doubt been asked multiple times before, I just want clarification that the following code will redirect any url on olddomain.com to the newdomain.com **homepage** not the equivalent url:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also if I wanted any subdomain on olddomain.com eg.subdomain.olddomain.com to go to the homepage of newdomain.com what would I have to do? Can I use a universal selector or would I have to write a condition for each subdomain like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.olddomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.olddomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of attempts are not correct as first will redirect:

```
http://olddomain.com/foobar to http://newdomain.com/foobar
```

not to the homepage of `newdomain`. Same is the problem with 2nd rule.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```